# Simple Scatter plot: variable issues on X axis

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I'm trying the plot a simple scatter plot: X axis is for student graduation term and Y axis is their GPA.

Below is how I read the data (Graduated08 is the file name):

```
Graduated08 <- read.csv (file="200804_Graduated.csv",
+                          header = TRUE,
+                          na.strings = "NA")
```

Below is the first a couple of rows of this data set:

```
Grad_Term          GPA
201302             3.560809
201403             3.013043
201202             4.000000
201302             3.344286
201204             3.596993
201401             3.393704
```

Above, 201302 stands for Spring term of 2013, 201202 stands for Spring term of 2012. Basically the naming convention is like this: the first four digits represent the year and the last two digits represent a particular term in that year (01-Winter term, 02-Spring term, 03-Summer term, 04-Fall term).

I used the following R codes to get a simple scatter plot

```
**> plot (x= Graduated08$Grad_Term,
+       y= Graduated08$GPA
+ )**
```

However, I got a plot that messed up with the X axis. Y axis looks fine, but X axis (Grad_Term) is messed up. Instead of having 201201, 201202, 201203 and 201204 separated out, the plot seems to group all these terms into one variable which is labeled as "201200". Same thing happened for other years (only see 201300, 201400 etc). I want to have all the four terms in a year be plotted out separately.

Comment: what is the output from `str(Graduated08)`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the `Grad_Term` column to be the `character` class.  However, R is treating this column as something other than `character`.  Use the following code to force `Grad_Term` to be `character`:

```
Graduated08 <- read.csv(file="200804_Graduated.csv",
                        header=TRUE,
                        colClasses=c("character", "numeric"),
                        na.strings="NA")

# now make your plot and each quarter should be a separate data point
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be `character`, any class where the `Grad_Term` is different should group appropriately. Without knowing the specifics of this case, diagnosis is impossible IMHO

Comment: Agreed.  I thought that R was treating the column as a factor but who knows.

Comment: My point is that if it is a factor, that should be fine, and (I would argue) more appropriate than character

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Tim in principle. However, I tried this on my end and plot() will automatically convert Grad_Term to numeric.

The easiest way to get around this is to turn off the automatic plotting initially, then add in custom x-axis values

```
d<-data.frame(rbind(
  cbind(201302,3.560809),
  cbind(201403,3.013043),
  cbind(201202, 4.000000),
  cbind(201302,3.344286),
  cbind(201204, 3.596993),
  cbind(201401,3.393704)))
names(d)<-c('Grad_Term','GPA')

attach(d)

# this is wrong
plot(Grad_Term,GPA)

# try this:
# turn off axis with xaxt= paramter
plot(Grad_Term,GPA,xaxt='n')

# put in your own, custom x axis
axis(1,at=Grad_Term)
```

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about the grouping of the variables, not the axis label

Comment: @alexwhan, it's my understanding that the  concern is about the "x-axis is messed up." To address your point, however, R is treating Grad_Term as a numeric, continuous variable...which is the right thing to do.

There is no grouping issue here, unless we want Grad_Term to be a factor, which will change each dot on the plot to a mini-boxplot.

Comment: @alexwhan: AO 's understanding is correct. It is about the X axis rather than grouping of the variables, and I'm trying to separate out all those terms on X axis.

Comment: @AO: the plot is what exactly I wanted, however, I have thousands of line of data including variables other than GPA and term that need to be read in. Therefore, I can't type in all the data as what you did. Also, my understanding is that by writing the codes you suggested, the automatic plotting will be turned off. Just wanted to make sure that I don't have to do anything else to turn auto plotting off, correct?